# Get Image path as per the package exported directory

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli-3

I am trying some ways by tweaking webpack configuration. Here is my problem -

I have vue component package `@foo/atom` in which there are some components which use static images internally by importing them as `module`

**Custom Component in package**

```
import logo from '@/assets/logo.svg'

data() {
 return {
  logo
 }
}

<img :src="logo" />
```

Now when i build the package this image from assets get exported to `lib/img/logo.123123.svg`, using `vue-cli` command

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --dest lib --name foo ./src/components/index.js
```

Now when i include this component to my vue app, say

```
import { CustomComponent } from '@foo/atom'

<CustomComponent />
```

and start the local server, the image gets `404` and when I am inspecting the path it looks like

```
http://localhost:3001/js/img/logo.123123.svg
```

The problem here is that when my local-server starts webpack append the local build directory before the relative path of the image which is `http://localhost:3001/js/` where it should be `node_module/@foo/atom/lib/img` because images are stored there.

I thought that I can simply copy all the `node_module/@foo/atom/lib/img` to app's root `src/assets` directory but that doesn't worked too.

I am stuck here and any clue or direction will be appreciated. Let me know if there some other information required too.

Comment: You can try to make a webpack alias/resolve for that 

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: thanks @Lhew however I am not sure if that will work as component get exported as build chunk, and i somehow need to tell the chunk to use `./` directory instead the relative path when it gets build